# How to use multi value in rotate property css

Tags: html, css, rotation

I want to rotate my element use `rotate: ;`.

I tried `rotate: x 10deg y 20deg;` or `rotate: x 10deg, y 20deg;` or `rotate: 10deg 20deg;`,it's seem not work.
If I use `rotate: x 10deg;  rotate: y 20deg;`, the **X** rotate not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both the `rotate` and `transform: rotate3d()` properties accept a vector plus angle value syntax taking the form of: `rotate: x y z a;` and `transform: rotate3d(x, y, z, a);`.

The `x`, `y` an `z` arguments are coordinates of the vector denoting the axis of rotation which could be between 0 and 1. The `a` argument is the degree of rotation.
What you're trying to do might be difficult to convert into that syntax unless you're familiar with vectors.

Your best bet might still be using transform, as it will allow you to combine multiple transforms more simply:

```css
.rotated {
  transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(20deg);
}
```

To transform only on `:hover`, you can just set the transform to `none` in the default state:

```css
.rotate {
  transform: none;
  transition: transform 2s;
}
.rotate:hover {
  transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your rep, that is new knowledge for me. But I don't really like `transform`. Ex, if I want to change something when `hover`, I must rewrite all methods in `transform`.

Comment: I see, fair enough, still possible but not as simple as you might want without transform. I've updated my answer accordingly.